# Ionic 6 Android 11 Video Player mp4 getting: Access to this video was denied

Tags: html5-video, android-11, ionic6

I'm trying to use a video player, in Ionic 6, I tried many options, fluidplayer, flowplayer, video html5 tag, but I'm getting access denied.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    <application ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Home.page.html

```html
<ion-content>
  <video id="video" style="width:100%;" class="ion-padding" preload="auto">
    <source src="/assets/sample5s.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
  
  <div
  class="flowplayer-embed-container"
  style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width:100%;">
  <iframe
    style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
    src="//ljsp.lwcdn.com/api/video/embed.jsp?id=3afc64ea-fe85-456c-b9d7-6d1de8350ff2&pi=cad9d975-ccae-4757-88a3-a65ebb7419f8"
    title="0" byline="0" portrait="0"
    width="640" height="360"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="autoplay">
  </iframe>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: The HTML5 video looks like it is a local file on the Android device while the flowplayer ons looks like it is a video hasted on the internet. Was this your intent?

Comment: Hello @Mick, I'm facing problems, I'm getting errors, I want to play videos using flowplayer or fluidplayer (native players)

Comment: Where is the video you want to play located, on the web or on the devices local storage?

Comment: local, in the assets folder of ionic. Ionic is a hybrid platform, it runs over an Activity in Android, inside a Browser view, an Ionic app installs using apk, it runs a local server in the device, in Ionic we work using angular, it seems a native app, but it is local web page.

Comment: I think the Flowplayer embedded iframe might be a bit of a distraction above. There does seem to be issues with Ionic and HTML5 video on Android. In your case, focusing on the HTML5 rather than Flowplayer, I would experiment with the file path which I'm not sure if correct above and look at the console logs closely. There is some good info, albeit Iconic 4, here: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-media-files-guide

Comment: Thanks Mick, I solved the HTML5 video tag issue, I forgot the controls attribute, but flowplayer still has problems